# Django: Is there a way to make sure that only a unique FK related object can be added/related to the PK object?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say there is a poll app and I want a user to vote only once for a poll question.

Assume `models.py` to be as follows,

```
class PollUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)

class PollQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    issuing_user = models.ForeignKey(PollUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PollChoice(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Is there a way to implement this functionality, without making this check in the views?

Comment: use a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) instead of `ForeignKey`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat What happens when an attempt to add multiple objects is made to a OneToOne Field?

Comment: [IntegrityError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError) will be thrown.